# How can I count across several relationships in django

Tags: python, django, aggregate

For a small project I have a registry of matches and results. Every match is between teams (could be a single player team), and has a winner. So I have `Match` and `Team` models, joined by a `MatchTeam` model. This looks like so (simplified)<sup>see below for notes</sup>

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ...

class Match(models.Model):
    teams = ManyToManyField(Team, through='MatchTeam')
    ...

class MatchTeam(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, related_name='matchteams',)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    winner = models.NullBooleanField()
    ...
```

Now I want to do some stats on the matches, starting with looking up who is the person that beats you the most. I'm not completely sure how to do this, at least, not efficiently.

In SQL (just approximating here), I would mean something like this:

```
SELECT their_matchteam.id, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM matchteam AS your_mt  
JOIN matchteam AS their_mt ON your_mt.match_id = their_mt.match_id
WHERE your.matchteam.id IN <<:your teams>> 
  your_matchteam.winner = false
GROUP BY their_matchteam.team_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

<sup>(this also needs a "their_mt is not your_mt" clause btw, but the concept is clear, right?)</sup>

While I have not tested this as SQL, it's just to give an insight to what I'm looking for: I want to find this result via a Django aggregation.

According to the manual I can annotate results with an aggregation, in this case a `Count`. Joining `MatchTeams` straight on `MatchTeams` as I'm doing in the SQL is a bit of a shortcut maybe, as there 'should' be a `Match` in between? At least, I wouldn't know how to translate that into Django

So maybe I need to find certain matches for my team, and then annotate them with the count of the *other* team? But what is 'the other team'?

Quick write-up would look like:

```
nemesis = Match.objects \
        .filter(matchteams__in=yourteams) \
        .annotate(cnt=Count('<<otherteam>>')).order_by('-cnt')[0]
```

If this is the right track, how should I define the `Count` here. 
And if it's not the right track, what is?

<sup>As is, this is all about teams instead of users. This is just to keep things simple :)</sup>

An additional question might be: should I even do this with that Django ORM stuff, or am I better off just adding SQL? That has the obvious disadvantage that you're stuck with writing very generic code (is this even possible?) or fixing your DB-backend. If not needed, I'd like to avoid that.

---

About the model: I really want to understand what I can change about the model to make it better, but I can't really see a solution without downsides. Let me try to explain:

I want to support matches with arbitrary amount of teams, so for instance a 5-team-match. This means I have many-to-many relationship and not one that is for instance 1 match to 2 teams. If that was the case, you could denormalize and put the winners/scores in the team table. But this is not the case.

Extra data about the results of one team (e.g. their final score, their time) is by definition a property of the relation. It cannot go into the `team` table (as it would be per match and you can have an undefined amount of matches), and it cannot go in the match table for the same reason mutatis mutandis.

Example: I have teams A,B,C,D and E playing a match. Team A and Team B have 10 points, the rest all have 0 points. I want to save the amount of points, and that Team A and Team B are the winners of this match.

So to the comments suggesting I need a 'better' design, by all means, if you have one I would gladly see it, but if you want to support what I support, it's going to be hard.

And as a final remark: This data can be easilly retrieved in SQL, so the model seems fine to me: I'm just too much of a beginner in Django to be able to do it in Django's ORM!

Comment: Is there a reason why you designed your models like this so that you can't even find who beat who? I think you should rethink your database schema.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say this? I can easily find out who beat who. Just select the matchteams that have `winner=true`. This scheme allows for matches between multiple teams, e.g. 3 teams in one match, but it's quite simple to find out who won as you can see. It's just harder for me to find out what opposing team beat you the most times, that's why I asked that question.

Comment: ManyToManyField is already joined  `Team` and `Match` models. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @AjaySingh I don't really see what you are refering to here, how can I use that information to return the aggregated data I need? I know I have a many to many field, I specified the trough table so I could add some data about that connection (e.g. if the team was a winner). But I'm not sure I see what that link has to offer as for an answer to my question?

Comment: IMO it would have been better to put the `winner` field in the Match model and make it reference the winner team. I am pretty sure it would save you headaches.

Comment: @Tryph but that won't work if you have a tie, especially in multi-team situations; example: if you have 5 teams, where 2 teams are (tied) winners. How would you propose to represent that in your model? You can not do this in a row in the `Match` model, as you would need a row per team. The same goes for score: if you want to save details (time, score, etc) per team, you want to do this "per team per match", which is the definition of the actual table. So if you have a many to many relation where the actual data belongs to that relation, this seems a valid solution?

Comment: @Nanne If tied matches are possible, your models seem ok. You could also have an other many-to-many field 'winners' in your match model but it would not bring so much profit compared to your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny problem ! I think I have the answer (get the team that beats `yourteams` the most):

```
Team.objects.get( # the expected result is a team
    pk=list( # filter out yourteams
        filter(lambda x: x not in [ y.id for y in yourteams ],
            list( 
                Match.objects # search matches
                .filter(matchteams__in=yourteams) # in which you were involved
                .filter(matchteams__winner=False) # that you loose
                .annotate(cnt=Count('teams')) # and count them
                .order_by('-cnt') # sort appropriately
                .values_list('teams__id', flat=True) # finally get only pks
            )
        )
    )[0] # take the first item that should be the super winner
)
```

I did not test it explicitly, but if does not work, I think it may be the right track.

Comment: I'll have to debug it a bit, as currently it returns, I think, an empty set in that inner list -> it returns `IndexError: list index out of range`. But this is a quick test in a shell, so I'll have to test it in a more filled env. If you can think of why this is, that's good, but ill test some more later

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure what goes wrong: the `list-filter-list()` seems to work, and produces an array of matches. so the [0] should work (but it doesn't, and it gives the error `list index out of range`). Apart from that error, the inner part seems to be `pk=<<a match>>`, but is that right? as in, it would expect an INT, not a match-object, right?

Comment: Obviously, my answer does not work if,for instance, `yourteams` win all matches, giving the error `list index out of range`. I think you have to do your stuff with several steps (2, or more?), checking each for particular cases. Another  special case occurs when you have 2 (or more) teams which beat `yourteams` equally.

Comment: yeah, good point, I kinda figured that much, so I was sorta just checking the basic case where you would have a single result. I have a test-setup with 1 lost match which should be ok to test this, but i'm not sure why that index pops up: the 'outer' list does return a match if run seperately, so that's ok. The strange thing is, the complete thing does the index error (which I can't explain, as there is an 'array' there). If I assing that outer list expression to a variable (and take the `[0]`), and then go `Team.objects.get(pk=<<variable>>), I get a different error, (int expected)

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to go from a match object to the correct team there. The side-issues about the no answers I can fix seperately, but if you can help me with this i'd be gratefull. (also, an obvious +1 for the great effort ;) )

Comment: I can't explain the errors you have, `int expected`, as the `values_list('teams__id')` must return a list of int. Maybe you can look the inner queryset of `Match` objects. It should return a list of `Team` ids, with `yourteams` first. Maybe you can test with just one team instead of the list `yourteams`.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it should, but it doesn't in my test case. Most probably cause: flawed test case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
matches_won_aginst_my_team = MatchTeam.objects.filter(team=my_team, winner=False).select_related(matches)    
teams_won_matches_aginst_my_team = matches_won_aginst_my_team.filter(winner=True).values_list('matchteams__team')
```

But as suggested you can probably model better.
I would hold two fields in the MatchModel: home_team, away_team.
Simpler and more indicative.

Comment: I did add to my question that I'm supporting 3 or more teams per match, so just like the other commenters: it's easy to say I need to model differently, but your "simple" solution does not support that usecase.

Comment: Point well taken.